# Why is some frozen breaded chicken pre-fried?

Tags: chicken, frying

At the supermarket, I found some frozen breaded chicken. The package said it was already fried before frozen. Why would they fry the chicken before freezing it?

Answer (score 7):

To simply facilitate the end-user cooking.

You get all the "benefit" of fried food without the hassle of having to actual fry the food (hot oil handling, odors, ... )

Most people do not have fryers at home and rely on par-fried food (for example oven fries).

Comment: and typically it's fully cooked, so you can just warm and eat ... so they have less chance of food poisoning from undercooked poultry.

Comment: Yes, you are right; Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: Just be sure to check  the package as most pre-cooked frozen foods (such as the fried chicken) still specify that the foods need to reach a certain internal temperature.